# C programming pointer conversions with GTK

Tags: c, pointers, gtk, x11, gtkentry

It appears that in GTK you hold a reference to an object, for example like an `GtkEntry`, but you hold it with a pointer to a `GtkWidget`. For example

```
GtkWidget* pointer = gtk_entry_new();
```

Then when you want to do something like set the text of that entry, you have to call a function and do something with that pointer.

```
gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(pointer), "hello");
```

A few questions:

> 1. What is the "GTK_ENTRY()" thing? Is it a function call or typecast?
> 2. Why is it in all Capital letters, why not do something like (GtkEntry*)pointer?
> 3. Why even do this? Why not return a GtkEntry pointer when you create a new Entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GTK_ENTRY is a macro, behaving like a function. It casts its argument to `GtkEntry*`, but it may - depending on macros like NDEBUG - do additional check to verify that provided argument may be cast.

It is in all CAPITAL because that is the general convention in C for macros.

The function `gtk_entry_new` returns `GtkWidget*` and not `GtkEntry*` more functions in GTK operates on `GtkWidget*`, and C language does not provide inheritance so the conversion cannot be automatic.

Comment: What is better to use, a macro rather than a conversion like (GtkEntry*)pointer

Comment: Macro is better because it is safer - it performs the check. Just the cast would perform the conversion blindly and some errors would not be visible immediately. This is how GTK emulates classes and inheritance.

Comment: How come GTK says it has ancestry but there is no inheritance in C?

Comment: GTK emulates it. More details at http://www.gtk.org/tutorial1.2/gtk_tut-22.html#ss22.2